# Smooth complex function interpolating sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Given a sequence $a_n\,\, n\in\mathbb{N},\quad a_n \in \mathbb{R}$, (or $\mathbb{C}$) under which conditions on $a_n$ does exist a complex smooth function (holomorphic, meromorphic, etc.) that interpolate perfectly all points of $a_n$ (i.e. $f(n)=a_n$)?
When such function exists (for example the Gamma function with the sequence of factorials $a_n=(n-1)!$), it's unique? Under which conditions?

I think the Real case is trivial (always exists such function) and there's not uniqueness, because we always can "paste" together pieces of functions in $C^\infty$ way, and there are many ways to do that. Correct?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have $f(n) = a_n$.

In that case, there is a holomorphic function doing what you want. More generally, if $\{ z_n \}$ is a sequence *without accumulation points* in $\mathbb{C}$ and $\{ a_n \}$ is *any* sequence of complex numbers, there is an entire function with $$ f(z_n) = a_n. $$

This follows for example from combining Weierstrass theorem (every set without accumulation points is the zero set of an entire function) and Mittag-Leffler's theorem (every set without accumulation points is the pole set of a meromorphic function, and it's possible to prescribe the principal part of the meromorphic function at those points).

Comment: Firstly, thank you, and yes I want $f(n)=a_n$ foreach $n$ natural number, I admit the question wasn't so clear, I apologise. I can't get the link between Weierstrass theorem, which talks abuot zeros if I understand correctly, and a generic sequence $a_n$, in my case with the constraint $z_n=n$. Furthermore, is $\infty$ an accumulation point in this case maybe?

Comment: @SebaF_it Yes, $\infty$ will be an accumulation point (but $\infty\notin\mathbb{C}$). For the construction, take the function from Weierstrass theorem and multiply it with a suitably chosen function from Mittag-Leffler's theorem.

Comment: For the construction you mean that I can pick a function with roots foreach $n$ in naturals ad a meromorphic function with poles foreach $n$ and residues chosen in order to have $f(n)=a_n$?